# How do I text wrap to next acrofield in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

how do I get text to wrap from one acrofield to the next? I have an adobe pdf doc our client gave us. It has acro fields one atop another (all with the same name). They want the text to wrap from one to another when it reaches the end of the line. All the other examples I see out there do not deal with filling in acro fields that wrap. Please help!

```
                // loop through disabilities and display them
                foreach (var disability in formNature.Disabilities)
                {
                    fields.SetField("EVALUATION", disability.PrimaryDisabilityName + "; ");
                }
```

in theory this should loop through all the disabilities they had entered on the web form and display them one after another while text-wrapping when it reaches the end of each line. But instead it only displays one item one the field.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer unfortunately.

First, when you call `SetField()` you are erasing the current contents of the field and replacing it with your new value. When done in a loop only the last value will ever be stored then. What you need to do is loop through each value and concatenate them into one big string.

```
string buf = '';
foreach (var disability in formNature.Disabilities)
{
    buf += disability.PrimaryDisabilityName + "; ";
}
buf = buf.Trim();
```

Second, the PDF standard to the best of my knowledge does not support chaining of fields for overflow which is what you are looking for. The only way that I know of to accomplish what you are trying is to actually measure the strings and compare them to the widths of the fields and truncate them as needed. To do this you will need to find the font used for the given field, create a `BaseFont` from it and use that to Measure the string. Then compare that with the field's rectangle and use only the characters that "fit" into that field. Repeat as needed.

That all said, I would **really really recommend** that you just edit the PDF and replace the multiple fields with one large field that supports multiple lines. Your life will be much, much easier.

Comment: Yeah, PDF is not for Word Publishing, but optimised for final delivery/portability. You being the programmer are the simulated word publishing software. I have the same problem myself: using SetField, and so i will need to use PdfCell to measure the string (without adding to the document) to detect when spillover is occuring.